# How to invoke a commonly used MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

With using a *nix command-line shell, I can conveniently create an alias for my commonly used commands. I'd like to do something similar with MySQL CLI client. One common that I frequently run is:

```
select option_value from wp_options where option_name = 'home' or option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Is there a way to do so, so that I call "siteurl" and the result of the above spits out?

Yes I'm roughly familiar with stored procedures and functions though I'm unaware of how they can be globally used against an instance.

Comment: Have you heard of [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html)?

Comment: Yes I have, but not how to use them for all databases of a mysql instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, try adding this to your `.bashrc` (perform the proper substitutions with your database access information):

```
alias siteurl='mysql -u<youruser> -p<yourpassword> <yourdatabase> -e "select option_value from wp_options where option_name = 'home' or option_name = 'siteurl';"
```

After that, every shell you'll open will have the command (alias) `siteurl` available, which will output the result of that query.

Comment: I like this, except for having my password in my shell's history, so I could leave the -p empty. Thanks!